# How can I improve the performance of my python function's for loop?

Tags: python

I have a function which is applied to every row of a pandas dataframe. The main use of it is to query a REST API (Azure's Text analytics API) and return a list of the resulting entities.

```
def get_entity_rec(row):
    try:
        textcon = row._c0[0:5000]
        doc = [textcon]
        textconlang = row._c0[0:1000]
        doclang = [textconlang]
        # Get Language
        response = client.detect_language(documents = doclang, country_hint = 'us')[0]
        row['language'] = response.primary_language.name
        result = client.recognize_entities(documents = doc)[0]
        row['items'] = [[entity.text, entity.category, entity.subcategory, entity.confidence_score] for entity in result.entities]
        return row
    except Exception as err:
        print("Encountered exception. {}".format(err))

d = {'_c0': ['London', 'Paris'], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

pd_df2 = df.apply(get_entity_rec, axis=1)

pd_df2
```

I originally had a for loop like this:

```
     for entity in result.entities:
             b = [entity.text, entity.category, entity.subcategory, entity.confidence_score]
             a.append(b)
             row['items'] = a
     return row
```

But looking around it seemed like list comprehension would perform better. However, after making the change I get pretty much the same runtime for both (sometime the for loop is a little faster)

Comment: The bottleneck is the API call. The loop overhead is almost certainly negligible.

Comment: did you profile your program?

Comment: I think the question is better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) so you might want to ask over there.

Comment: If the algorithm needs to run on every row, but the order doesn't matter, maybe try making it async so multiple rows could be run simultaniosly